# Changing the complete background colour of a combobox when style is dropdownlist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events

I am trying to achieve a red background for the combo box as a form of validation, however when I set the background to red it is not visible only when clicked for the drop down list (See Image 2). Thanks :-)

**Image 1**: Validating user input null as red background, as you can see the drop down list is not red but meets this validation criteria.

[image]

**Image 2**: Shows that I have tried to change the background through properties but only success for the part of which is the list, not the initial box.

[image]

Comment: If required I can show my code but it is very simple, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code for change back color of comboBox

```
[comboboxname].BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Yes I have already tried that which leads to the red dropdown but not the initial box.

Comment: But this can also change initial box also, I also tried by changing combo box property to dropdown list

Comment: Yes this is the code I tried before but it did not work, it looks exactly the same as image 2 above, where the drop down is red.

Comment: can you give a sample code where you change, i.e in which event you change background color, then i will check on my end also